# not able to create modern page in office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I'm trying to create a modern page in one of the site collections

I checked the site settings and the `"Site Pages"` feature is active

[image]

But when I try clicking on the "Add new page" it only creates a normal page and it's not creating a modern page

Even in the Sitepages Library I don't get new `site page` option under the **new** ribbon, even though the content type is attached to the library

Comment: Check all settings: http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/creating-site-page-for-enabling-modern-ui-experience-in-office-365-sharepoint-online-22189.aspx and restart IIS

Comment: Is that possible to enable for a single admin user as the tenancy is shared with multiple countries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably because you dont have the setting enabled at the tenant level.

Go to you SharePoint admin center > Settings and then modify the Site Pages setting to `Allow users to create Site Pages`.

The admin center settings url would be:

`https://tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/TenantSettings.aspx`

[image]

Once you change this, wait for a couple of hours and then you will be able to create modern site pages using `Add a page` option or via the Site pages library

Comment: should I do anything else after changing it in site settings level?

Comment: Nope, once it is set at tenant level, that option will appear in few hours. No need to change anything at site level, just keep the site pages feature activated.